# Use payable modifier for function that creates new contract?

Tags: solidity, contract-design, contract-invocation

The users are going to use a function that costs gas, but requires no Ether otherwise. Should I use the payable modifier in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No.**

The gas they gas pass into the function that does the create will be used to pay for the create. There isn't currently any crossover from `payable`/ether received/`msg.value` to gas fees.

The user who sends a transaction to the function that deploys a contract will pay the cost of deploying the contract in the original transaction gas. It's just part of the cost of running that function.